# Получить query.from.id всех пользователей в группе?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Создаю telegram bot на node-telegram-bot-api. Задача такова - нужно получить массив всех id пользователей которые находятся в группе с ботом, что бы можно было отправить им личное сообщение от бота. Условие с активацией бота каждым пользователем выполнена. Я могу получить id одного пользователя при условии что в этой группе он нажал на условную кнопку ('start') инлайн клавы. Код ниже для примера. А что если я хочу что бы при нажатие кнопки 'start', сообщения получили все пользователи одновременно, такое возможно?

```js
bot.on('callback_query', async(query) => {
  const data = query.data
  const userId = query.from.id

  switch (data) {
    case 'start':
      await bot.sendMessage(userId, 'some text for user')
      break
  }
})
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос в том возможно ли это или как правильно это делать?) (Ответ на вопрос который вы задали - это возможно). А если вопрос "как сделать правильно" - то после нажатия на кнопку start вы должны сохранить идентификатор пользователя у себя в своем хранилище и при необходимости получить всех - брать список из своего хранилища

Comment: А, то-есть сделать что-то типа кнопки регистрации, после нажатия добавлять id в массив и уже с ним работать?

Comment: В массив / базу данных/..... т.е. у вас нет возможности запросить "айди всех кто в чате и иницировал общение с ботом" а вот реагировать на кнопки / входы в канал/ выходы из канала - вы можете и соответственно на своей стороне можете весьи список "своих" пользователей

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо, это отличный вариант

Answer (score 0):

Telegram Bot API не предоставляет такой функциональности, единственный способ сделать это — использовать **юзербота** (бота, работающего под обычной учетной записью Telegram).

Примером может послужить следующий GET запрос:
`https://api.telegram.org/токен/messages.getFullChat?chat_id=чат_ид`

Подробнее можете прочитать в документации: **[Telegram API (messages.getFullChat)](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getFullChat)**

Либо сохранять при присоединении к чату всех пользователей в базу данных и уже отсюда придумывать свою логику.